# Generate a random uuid in a maven archetype

Tags: maven, random, uuid, maven-archetype

I need to create a random UUID and write it to the generated project. Currently, I ask the user to fill in a random UUID each time a project is created, and I would like this to be done automatically.

Right now, I have in my archetype-metadata.xml the following required property:

```xml
<requiredProperty key="randomUuid">
     <defaultValue>12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678abcd</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Then I refer to `${randomUuid}` inside my archetype resources to write this UUID into the generated project.

Any better approach ?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this link can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984794/generating-uuid-through-maven

Comment: Thanks, the groovy snippet seem to solve the part of generating the UUID, however, I couldn't manage to make it execute when the user runs "mvn archetype:generate". Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I found myself needing the same thing, so here is what I did to make this work:

```html
    <requiredProperty key="testUUID">
        <defaultValue>${package.getClass().forName("java.util.UUID").getMethod("randomUUID").invoke(null).toString()}
        </defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
```