# Generate random number during Maven build

Tags: java, maven, random

Is there a plugin (or another easy way) to generate a "random" number as part of a Maven build? I would like to assign this number to a property that I can then use in the `pom.xml` file for some other purposes, e.g. for a filter value.

The number doesn't have to be completely random (hence the quotes), something using the current timestamp as a seed would be perfectly OK.

Comment: Please consider the gmaven-plugin as mentioning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984794/generating-uuid-through-maven

Comment: Yes, I've seen that option when looking for a possible solution. The timestamp is a lot simpler to use and works fine for me, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default installation of maven offers a variable named `maven.build.timestamp`, which gives you a timestamp. You can control the format with

```
  <properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
  </properties>
```

which follows the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) rules. So, you can simply just use `${maven.build.timestamp}` to get a formatted timestamp :)

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables

Comment: I was actually asking for a random number, but the timestamp will also work. Thanks!

Comment: I don't consider this as a valid answer because a timestamp is not a number, nor random. It is monotonic (in most cases).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the timestamp maven plugin : http://code.google.com/p/maven-timestamp-plugin/

It generates the timestamp in maven property in the format you like.

Comment: I was actually asking for a random number, but the timestamp will also work. I'm accepting the other answer, since it works without an additional plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [randomid-maven-plugin](https://github.com/infrastructurebuilder/randomid-maven-plugin)

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.infrastructurebuilder.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>randomid-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version> <!-- r
    <configuration>
      <randomConfigs>
        <randomConfig>
          <name>random</name> <!-- Default value -->
          <length>16</length>
          <lower>2</lower>
        </randomConfig>
      </randomConfigs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

You can change the special character set, length, etc and it'll let you generate a random UUID as a property.

Note that this *will* produce an unrepeatable build.  That's the nature of random.  But if you're just injecting a value that'll be used downstream but doesn't matter for repetability, this will do the trick.