# How to use Inno Setup in Maven build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, inno-setup

My Eclipse RCP application is built via Maven. I would love to automatically build a setup via Inno Setup. But I don't get where to include the Inno Setup exe and `.iss`, it should also be included in an automatic Jenkins build, so where to put Inno Setup?

This is what Google told me to do, but I always get an `IOException` because `ISCC.exe` cannot be found.

Has anyone ever done such Maven-Inno Setup-build?

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>ISCC.exe</executable>     
      <arguments>
        <argument>setup.iss</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure, that you put all of the innoSetup into the directory, you use. also make sure, that the filepaths dont get too long

Answer (score 2):

See the [`exec-maven-plugin:exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#executable) page:

> **executable**:
>
> The executable. Can be a full path or the name of the executable. In the latter case, the executable must be in the PATH for the execution to work.
>
> The plugin will search for the executable in the following order:
>
> 1. relative to the root of the project
> 2. as toolchain executable
> 3. relative to the working directory (Windows only)
> 4. relative to the directories specified in the system property PATH (Windows Only)
>
> Otherwise use the executable as is.

I'd also bind the plugin execution to the `package` phase rather than the `install` phase since it's [the more natural one](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference):

> `package` – take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format

and such you could also use the setup's result in the `integration-test` phase.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This results in the following:  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default) on project ***: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: -1073741515 (Exit value: -1073741515) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default) on project ***: Command execution failed.

Comment: @unknown404 `error: -1073741515` isn't too descriptive. What is the result if you run `ISCC.exe` with `setup.iss` on the command line in your project's directory after you built it? Is there a log file for `ISCC`?

Comment: thanks for the nice advice. running iscc.exe via console made it much more sensible. do you also know, how to let maven generate a GUID for my app-id?

Comment: @unknown404 Great that you solved your issue. Please add an answer with what the error really was and how you got rid of it, so that others can benefit from it in the future. For your question see [Generating UUID through Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3984794/1744774).

Comment: @unknown404 You also can accept your answer after a certain period (and upvote mine instead) with the chance to gather upvotes/reps in the future. See [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).